# In memory db that supports grouping

Tags: database, grouping, in-memory-database

I have about a million records which i want to store in memory and perform grouping,filtering,sorting etc.

I came to know about NEDb but it does not support grouping.
Is there any other fast and scalable in memory db that provides all operations?

Comment: For only a million rows any relational database will do, that is not a specifically large data set.

Comment: We have a very complex data. So i dont want to use relational database.

Comment: But "grouping", "filtering" and "sorting" are the things that relational database are really good at - especially with such a small dataset

Comment: Asking for libraries or tools is specifically off-topic for Stack Overflow. See the sister site [*Software Recommendations Stack Exchange*](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com). You will find [some existing Q&A on in-memory databases](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/search?q=database+memory). If none are relevant, post a list of your specific needs, the criteria by which you would select a product.

Answer (score 0):

For filtering and sorting *on key values*, any key-value store ought to suffice (redis, leveldb, berkeleydb, ...there are many).  Grouping is an aggregate operation that, as another commented, is a staple of relational databases.  Also, since the data is opaque in a key-value pair, it can be arbitrarily complex. Some key-value stores also support secondary indexes, so you can filter/sort on other attributes.

eXtremeDB (my company's product) has a native (nonSQL) interface, but is a structured database (meaning it has a schema language). The schema language is much like C++ (or you can use C# or Java for the schema language), so you can create arbitrarily complex objects (or even use the schema language to define a key-value pair). You can index any field, nested structure field, vector, or any combination. So it can also handle the filtering/sorting. If your data is time series data, then there's also a library of functions for various grouping operations (average, window average, grid average, many more). If it is not time series data, then just like key-value pair databases, you'll have to do the grouping operation yourself. It's not difficult with the support of the available filtering/sorting.